# In C# Return XElement without descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Sure this is simple, but it's alluding me at the moment, i want to return the top level node of an XDocument as an XElement, but without returning any of it's descendants:

Looking for something along the lines of below, but it doesn't work

```
XElement myElement = myXDocument.Root.Element();
```

WANT TO RETURN ONLY

```
<Response xmlns="someurl" xmlnsLi="thew3url">
</Response>
```

FROM

```
 <Response xmlns="someurl" xmlnsLi="thew3url">   
    <ErrorCode></ErrorCode>            
    <Status>Success</Status>    
    <Result>
    <Manufacturer>
                <ManufacturerID>46</ManufacturerID>
                <ManufacturerName>APPLE</ManufacturerName>
    </Manufacturer>    
    </Result> 
 </Response>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to go about doing this:

- Make a shallow copy of the `XElement`, and add attributes, or
- Make a deep copy of the `XElement`, and remove sub-elements.

The first way is less wasteful, especially when the element has lots of child nodes.

Here is the first way:

```
XElement res = new XElement(myElement.Name);
res.Add(myElement.Attributes().ToArray());
```

Here is the second way:

```
XElement res = new XElement(myElement);
res.RemoveNodes();
```

Comment: perfect, i knew it would be simple :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = "<Response xmlns=\"someurl\" xmlnsLi=\"thew3url\">"
                   + "<ErrorCode></ErrorCode>"
+ "<Status>Success</Status>"
+ "<Result>"
+ "<Manufacturer>"
            + "<ManufacturerID>46</ManufacturerID>"
            + "<ManufacturerName>APPLE</ManufacturerName>"
+ "</Manufacturer>"
+ "</Result>"
+ "</Response>";



        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        var root = doc.FirstChild;

        for (int i = root.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            root.RemoveChild(root.ChildNodes[i]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP requested how to do this with XDocument (Linq to Xml), not the older xml classes.

Comment: the code is an alternative to achieve the same result, what's the point of down rate it.

Comment: It doesnt answer his question on how to do it with xelement.  Its doable with those classes, so why would your answer only include an entirely different api?